# "Hold Cmd-Q to Quit" from Chrome

Tags: google-chrome

Has anyone else noticed that Chrome refuses to quit instantly when using <kbd>Cmd</kbd><kbd>Q</kbd>?

Happens with one or several tabs open...

All the other apps I run can be ended by typing / tapping briefly <kbd>Cmd</kbd><kbd>Q</kbd>, but Chrome insists that I have to hold for an appreciable period of time.

This is becoming annoying, any ideas?

Comment: This happens in MS Edge as well.

Answer (score 118, accepted):

This is a change - Chrome thinks this is correct default behavior and shipped this enabled.

- You can double press the Q - hold command and press and release Q twice as quickly as you are comfortable - <kbd>⌘</kbd> <kbd>Q</kbd> <kbd>Q</kbd>
- Or change the default to match your expectations and all other programs - see below to change the default setting

Select **Chrome** in the menu bar and select to un-check **Warn before Quitting (⌘Q)**

[image: Chrome main menu screenshot]

This can also be found in Chrome's **Preferences** (<kbd>Cmd</kbd><kbd>,</kbd>), in the **Appearance** section:

[image: Chrome Preferences - Appearance]

Comment: Thank you! Having to hold the key down has been driving me crazy.

Comment: You can report this content all you like.  But the product manager for Chrome for Mac should be fired for making this violation of Apple's user interface guidelines default behavior in Chrome.  It is horrible.

Comment: The command to quit and to close are so close together, some people mistakenly hit Q instead of W and lose web app data. If Chrome doesn't have windows open, it will quit instantly but if you have windows open, you would need to hold down to quit Chrome unless you disable it.

Comment: @netrox people can use the cmd+shift+t shortcut, or go trough the menu, to get all their pages and tabs back. This really is a non issue and google is just being annoying imo.

Comment: If you're interested in the history behind this weird design decision, check out the infamous issue 147 - https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=147&cnum=100&cstart=100 The "we know best" attitude of the Chromium devs in that thread put me off using Chrome for a long time.

Comment: Can this be set via the command line (e.g. defaults write)?

Answer (score 4):

Still happy with the answer given, **but** I did find out, by accident, that if you hold command and do a double tap on Q it quits instantly in spite of that option being selected.

Only found out as I have to quit chrome on computers in the lab often...

Answer (score -4):

This happens when you have multiple tabs open. Chrome takes its time to close tabs individually. The best way to save you time is to either close unnecessary tabs or use an app called "Onetab" which automatically closes your tabs and saves them all in one tab. After that, if you press <kbd>command</kbd> <kbd>q</kbd>, it'll work better. Hope this helped you.

Comment: Thanks for answering, I have tried this with one or several tabs open and its behaviour is the same whether one or 4... Am about to go off and find "Onetab"...

Comment: Kelly Choi that's not really the cause of the issue, as stated in the other answer

Comment: Not for me either, open a new chrome, single pane single window and no tabs, you have to double press Q to get it to quit or fiddle with the default preference to change this back.

Answer (score -6):

It's Apple failure in design. I agree with Google. What the h*ll Apple! An easy shortcut and all your work is gone. <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>F4</kbd> on Windows or GNOME (Ubuntu/Linux) is really way better.

Here is a Google explanation of this, I prefer the Workaround of bad design by Apple:

https://googlemac.blogspot.com/2011/06/q-i-didnt-mean-to-do-that.html

Comment: Ummmm, no to all of this.  It's not an "Apple thing" as you describe.  In fact, they encourage devs to implement [Auto Save](https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/macos/system-capabilities/auto-save/).  As for your key combo, ⌘-Q is no more/less effective than Alt-F4.  As far as browser windows go, all of them (Safari, Firefox, Chrome, etc.) all support "undo closed window" so you can get back to where you were.